# Проблема со считыванием dataframe в label pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

В jupyter необходимо построить помесячный график платежей по каждой стране (групповой barchart). Имеется два csv файла:[первый](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1dps.png), [второй](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbOHH.png) (скриншоты).

Пишу так:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on='customer_id')
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
df['new_date']  = df['created_at'].dt.month
df=df[['created_at', 'amount', 'country', 'new_date']].groupby(['new_date', 'country']).sum()

df=df.reset_index()
```

Но при попытке написать `labels=df['new_date']` возникает ошибка `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`. Судя по всему, это связано с тем, что разное кол-во месяцев получается. Как можно выйти из ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема решилась строкой

```
df.groupby(['new_date', 'country']).sum()['amount'].unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```